# How to retain the domain name while redirecting to my IP

Tags: django, redirect, amazon-web-services, nginx

App is using django, nginx and is hosted on aws.
Bought the domain name - `mygrounds.in` - from godaddy.

In godaddy,in DNS ZONE FILE page, changed the `points to` column to my aws IP.

On going to my domain name, it is redirected to my IP.
The redirecting part is right, but the problem is , i want the domain name to be retained while redirecting to my IP

**UPDATE :**

Here is the `project_config` file from dir:`nginx/sites_enabled/`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  54.186.220.140;

    # location /static/ {

    #    autoindex on;
        # alias "The static files path on your server machine"
    #    alias /home/seenu/tiger_review/staticfiles/;
    #}

    location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         # bind the gunicorn address
         proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
      }
 }
```

One of my colleague help me setup this config file. So not sure on the contents of the config file

**Expected behaviour:**

on going to `mygrounds.in/printo-app/login` i should be able to see my app.

Currently the site is live at `54.186.220.140/print-app/login`

Do ask, if more clarity is required.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Redirecting is the wrong thing to be doing, by its very definition, its *going* to redirect you.

Comment: By any means..... is your comment supposed to shed any light to my qn... if so..... i have not understood a word.....

Comment: Your web server is misconfigured, and is generating this redirect.

Comment: i am beginner in this...... so sorry for being a pain .............. Where shall i correct the server config ? in niginx config file ?

Comment: Please show your nginx config file and better explain expected behaviour. Do you want to still have your domain in URL (so no redirection at all) or do you want to inform django after redirection that user was redirected from that domain?

Comment: @GwynBleidD: config file attached to the qn

Comment: @GwynBleidD : added the expected behaviour also. Hope that makes it clear

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add your domain into server_name entry in your nginx config. All names should be separated by whitespaces, so if you want to preserve your site on that IP address, but add also ability to use it on domain, your server_name line should be:

```
   server_name  54.186.220.140 mygrounds.in;
```

If you want to serve your app only on domain, it should be:

```
   server_name  mygrounds.in;
```

Comment: i am accessing the `project_nginx` file after i ssh into the server..... and after i edit this file, while saving, it is showing this file is read-only ? Is this fine ?

Comment: should i change the nameservers in godaddy to the ones provided by aws, or the default nameservers provided by godaddy is enough ?...... and also should the forwarding option in godaddy be set to my IP